# Include doi in references - elsarticle-num.bst

Tags: cross-referencing, elsarticle, doi

I am writing a letter to Journal of Sound and Vibration(JSV).

JSV wants to put DOI in references.

Bit I can't put DOI in references

Here is my setting.

```
\documentclass[1p]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{lineno,hyperref}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{url}

\biboptions{numbers,sort&compress}

\modulolinenumbers[5]

\journal{Journal of Sound and Vibration}

\bibliographystyle{elsarticle-num}
\bibliography{myrefer}
```

This is example of bib file.

```
@article{tichy1983active,
  title={Active noise cancellation in ducts},
  author={Tichy, Jiri and Warnaka, Glenn E and Poole, Lynn A},
  journal={The Journal of the Acoustical Society of America},
  volume={74},
  number={S1},
  pages={S25--S25},
  year={1983},
  publisher={Acoustical Society of America}
  doi={10.1121/1.2020873}
}
```

How can I put DOI in my references?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A comma is missing: `publisher={Acoustical Society of America},` (I think that `publisher` is not used as field for article, perhaps `URL` or `eprint` are more useful)

[image: a]

Try this code

```
\documentclass[preprint,12pt]{elsarticle}   

\journal{Journal of Sound and Vibration}

\begin{document}

\begin{frontmatter}     
    \title{}    
    \author{}
    
    \affiliation{organization={},%Department and Organization
                addressline={}, 
                city={},
                postcode={}, 
                state={},
                country={}}
    
    \begin{abstract}
    \end{abstract}
    
    \begin{keyword}
    \end{keyword}   
\end{frontmatter}   

\section{}
\label{}    

See reference \cite{tichy1983active}.

\bibliographystyle{elsarticle-num} 
\bibliography{myrefer}

\end{document}
```

This is the corrected `myrefer.bib`

```
@article{tichy1983active,
    title={Active noise cancellation in ducts},
    author={Tichy, Jiri and Warnaka, Glenn E and Poole, Lynn A},
    journal={The Journal of the Acoustical Society of America},
    volume={74},
    number={S1},
    pages={S25--S25},
    year={1983},
    publisher={Acoustical Society of America},
    doi={10.1121/1.2020873}
}
```

Not related: This is the bibtex entry from the publisher side

```
@article{doi:10.1121/1.2020873,
author = {Tichy,Jiri  and Warnaka,Glenn E.  and Poole,Lynn A. },
title = {Active noise cancellation in ducts},
journal = {The Journal of the Acoustical Society of America},
volume = {74},
number = {S1},
pages = {S25-S25},
year = {1983},
doi = {10.1121/1.2020873},
URL = {https://doi.org/10.1121/1.2020873},
eprint = {https://doi.org/10.1121/1.2020873}
}
```

Comment: OMG! Thank your for your advise. I totally solved my problem.